# Overflow-x/y not working in IE

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer

Current IE version: 11
Website: www.4pia.com/beta

Right now I've tried testing the website using Firefox, Chrome and IE11. Chrome and Firefox both work with the `overflow` CSS. However, IE11 does not. When I tried changing the width/height in the CSS code it did not effect IE's rendering at all (so I assume that's where my problem lies). I'm not sure where I need to transfer to overflow code to make it work though.

CSS:

```
#repnews{
    float: right;
    width: 450px;
    height: 600px;
}

#reptable tbody{ 
    width: 450px;
    height: 600px;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    color: #000; 
    font-size: 11px; 
    font-weight: bold;
}

#reptable tr{
    max-width: 450px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

#reptable td{
    max-width: 360px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

HTML/PHP

```
<?php
echo "<div id='repnews'>";
echo "<div class='counter' align='right'>".$reptotal."<img src='images/rep.png'></div>";
echo "<hr class='repborder'>";
echo "<table id='reptable'>";

echo "<tr><td><div class='icon'><a href='/beta/bio?code=".$code."'>".$Name."</a> - ".$Tim;
echo "<img src='images/reply.png' class='tooltip' title='Please sign into Twitter to reply'>";
echo "<img src='images/retweet.png' class='tooltip' title='Please sign into Twitter or Facebook retweet'>";
echo "<img src='images/check.png' class='tooltip' title='Please sign in to vote'>";
echo "<img src='images/veto.png' class='tooltip' title='Please sign in to vote'>";
echo "</div></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td nowrap='wrap' width='360px'>".$Tweet."</td>";
echo "<td width='90px'><font color='green'>".$fol."<br>Followers</font></td></tr>";

echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: Instead of forcing the table to have `display: block`, which can lead to issues with layouts of tables (as the default is `display: table`), why not just wrap each table in a `<div>`, give it a height and set the overflow there?  Or even better use `<divs>` for the layout rather than tables as this isn't tabular data.

Comment: That's actually a lot cleaner too. I'll try that thank you!

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you are not using visible for either overflow-x or overflow-y and something other than visible for the other. The visible value is interpreted as auto.

http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

this can help [CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue)

Comment: EDIT x2: I've looked into the problem but it still seems to do do `overflow: visible` despite telling it to be `overflow-x:hidden` and `overflow-y: scroll`. I have no other `overflow` CSS in my code so I don't think it would inherent it from anywhere else.